# multiple taxonomy select display only one in front end

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, jquery, front-end

I have various custom taxonomy,

sometime, I have multiple choise selected in the back end ( cf screenshot)

[image]

however, in Front end, I have only one getting display, I would like to have all of them being display in front end . ..

This is the way I call them to display in front end:

```
  <?php
$taxonomy = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'category_job');
$locations = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'locations', array("fields" => "all"));
$types = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'types');
$sectors = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'sectors');
$salaries = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'salaries');
$price = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'price-range');
echo '<strong>Category:</strong> '.$taxonomy[0]->name.'<br>';
echo '<strong>Location:</strong> '.$locations[0]->name.'<br>';
echo '<strong>Sector:</strong> '.$sectors[0]->name.'<br>';
echo '<strong>Salary:</strong> '.$price[0]->name.'£'.'<br>';
echo '<strong>Type:</strong> '.$types[0]->name.'<br>';

?>
```

any help would be amazing :)

Thank you for your time guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a loop to display all taxonomy :

```
if (2 > count($locations)) {
    echo '<strong>Location:</strong> '.$locations[0]->name.'<br>';
} else {

    echo "<strong>Location:</strong>";

    echo "<ul>";

    foreach ($locations as $l) {
        echo "<li>";
        echo $l->name;
        echo "</li>";
    }

    echo "</ul>";

}
```

.
other loop with all location on the same line

```
    $stack = array();

    foreach ($locations as $l) {
        $stack[] = $l->name;
    }

    echo "<strong>Location:</strong>" . implode(";", $stack) . "<br/>";
```

Comment: just a fast question, If i wish to add a coma ',' between each list, except the last one... how can i achieve this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: arf, im sorry but i dont manage to see which part should i put it ... :( Im having a erorr message each time :(